# JS FileReader: Read Excel and CSV from Local File and display on a table

Tags: javascript, html

I am allowing a user to upload a CSV or Excel file. I want to allow them to view the contents of the file upload before submitting it.

The upload works well but the display fails for Excel files.

It works for CSV files but I am unable to view the contents of Excel files here. Outputs some texts.

```js
var lines = [];
$("#import_file").change(function(e) {
var ext = $("input#import_file").val().split(".").pop().toLowerCase();
    if ($.inArray(ext, ["csv", "xlsx", "xls"]) == -1) {
        alert("Please upload a valid CSV or Excel file.");
        return false;
    }
    if (e.target.files != undefined) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            lines = e.target.result.split('\r\n');
            $('#contactsAlert').css('display', 'block');
            $('#contactsAlert').text('Confirm the sample contacts are OK');
            for (i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
                if (i === 11) {
                    break;
                }

                $('tableHtml').append('<table style="width:100%"><tr><th></th></tr><tr> <td>' + lines[
                    i] + '</td></tr></table>');

            }
        };
        reader.readAsText(e.target.files.item(0));
    }
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" required accept=".xlsx, .xls, .csv" name="import_file" id="import_file">
   
<span id="contactsAlert"></span>
<tableHtml />
```

Will someone let me know what am missing? You can test with any sample Excel or CSV file.

Thanks.

Comment: Excel files aren't really text, why would you want to display their content as a sequence of text lines?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [SheetJS](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs). It can read and handle spreadsheet files (.csv, .ods, xlsx, ...) in browser.

SheetJS has a [demo](https://oss.sheetjs.com/) which load and display spreadsheet files.